# .NET Core HTTP GET

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have HTTP GET method in .NET Core Controller as below:

```
   [HttpGet]
        [Route("chat/conversation")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<ChatMessageDto>> GetConversation([FromQuery]long senderId, [FromQuery]long recipientId)
        {
            var result = await _appController.GetOrderedConversation(senderId, recipientId);
            return result;
        }
```

I am trying to get there by url as below

```
http://localhost:55916/chat/conversation?senderId=2&recipientId=5
```

I am getting 500 Internal Server Error. HttpContext.Request when debuggin contains query with 2 items [senderId, recipientId]. Why is it 500 ?

Comment: Because there are errors in your `_appCotroller.GetOrderedConversation`, you need to implement some sort of full logs to see exact exception.

Comment: But it doesnt even hit breakpoint inside

Comment: What if you take the parameters out of the method and call the URL without a querystring?
Can you post the exception details? You should be able to get it from intellitrace or implement some proper logging to find out what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [little tool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/) to see what routes you have configured and go from there.